# Algorithm: Triangle with two constraints, each corner on a given line

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

Some time ago I asked a question on math.stackexchange and got an answer. I have difficulties deriving an algorithm from that answer because my background is in design and hope some of you can help me.

The original question with visual sketch and possible answer are here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667432/triangle-with-two-constraints-each-corner-on-a-given-line

The question was: Given 3 3-dimensional lines (a, b and c) that coincide in a common point S and a given Point B on b, I'm looking for a point A on a and a point C on c where AB and BC have the same length and the angle ABC is 90 degrees.

I will have to implement this algorithm in an imperative language, any code in C++, Java, imperative pseudo-code or similar is fine.

Also, different approaches to this problem are equally welcome. Plus: Thanks for any hints, if the complete solution is indeed too time-consuming!

Comment: I tried to understand the answer :) I understand the first part of the answer but can't follow through with cubic equations and don't understand the whole second half with the conic intersection. I'm simply missing the mathematical background and decided to ask for help again.

Comment: What I meant is, what have you tried so far codewise?

Comment: I wanted to understand the answer first. I can't implement an algorithm because I can't transform the answer into imperative steps because I don't understand the answer in the first place. Coding will (probably) not be the problem, because the problem is primarily a mathematical one, that's why I don't care about the language used in a solution here. As long as the solution is not too concisely expressed in a functional language.

Comment: Seems a lot like you're asking us to write a program for you, rather than asking help on a program you're working on. In any case, I can't help you with this, cause I don't understand that mathematical answer either.

Comment: No, I'm not asking for a program. All I'm asking for is: If someone understands the mathematical answer, it's maybe not too time-consuming to sketch out an algorithm in pseudo-code. If it is, no problem, I don't ask here expecting everything/anything but hoping for any help or hints. And this problem is of course part of a larger program I'm working on.

Comment: @user479864: I'm working on an explicit solution but starting from a different approach. I've an explicit equation for a scalar `t` that can find the point on line `C` (from which a trivial computation can find the other point on line `A`). This equation is however AFAIKT a generic fourth degree equation and thus I'll implement an explicit numeric solver instead of filling pages with symbolic formulas.

Comment: @6502 Forgot to mention that different approaches are great too. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm leaving now but I'll post later a reply with a Python solver for this problem.

Comment: Do you know anything specific about a, b, c, S, and B, or do you need to do this for all possible values of those variables?

Comment: @Teepemm Needs to work with all possible values. That being said, it's possible that there will be no solution in certain situations, e.g. if the angles between a, b and c are too large and a triangle with said constraints will not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two key formulas are

[image]

(I've replied the derivation for the formulas in the mathematics stack exchange site)

Substituting the first in the second gives in the end a 4th degree equation that is quite annoying to solve with a closed form. I've therefore used instead a trivial numerical solver in Python:

```
# function to solve (we look for t such that f(t)=0)
def f(t):
    s = (t*cB - B2) / (t*ac - aB)
    return s*s - 2*s*aB - t*t + 2*t*cB

# given f and an interval to search generates all solutions in the range
def solutions(f, x0, x1, n=100, eps=1E-10):
    X = [x0 + i*(x1 - x0)/(n - 1) for i in xrange(n)]
    Y = map(f, X)
    for i in xrange(n-1):
        if (Y[i]<0 and Y[i+1]>=0 or Y[i+1]<0 and Y[i]>=0):
            xa, xb = X[i], X[i+1]
            ya, yb = Y[i], Y[i+1]
            if (xb - xa) < eps:
                # Linear interpolation
                # 0 = ya + (x - xa)*(yb - ya)/(xb - xa)
                yield xa - ya * (xb - xa) / (yb - ya)
            else:
                for x in solutions(f, xa, xb, n, eps):
                    yield x
```

The search algorithm samples the function in the interval and when it finds two adjacent samples that are crossing the f=0 line repeats the search recursively between those two samples (unless the interval size is below a specified limit, approximating the function with a line and computing the crossing point in that case).

I've tested the algorithm generating random problems and solving them with

```
from random import random as rnd

for test in xrange(1000):
    a = normalize((rnd()-0.5, rnd()-0.5, rnd()-0.5))
    b = normalize((rnd()-0.5, rnd()-0.5, rnd()-0.5))
    c = normalize((rnd()-0.5, rnd()-0.5, rnd()-0.5))

    L = rnd() * 100
    B = tuple(x*L for x in b)

    aB = dot(a, B)
    cB = dot(c, B)
    B2 = dot(B, B)
    ac = dot(a, c)

sols = list(solutions(f, -1000., 1000.))
```

And there are cases in which the solutions are 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4. For example the problem

```
a = (-0.5900900304960981, 0.4717596600172049, 0.6551614908475357)
b = (-0.9831451620384042, -0.10306322574446096, 0.15100848274062748)
c = (-0.6250439408232388, 0.49902426033920616, -0.6002456660677057)
B = (-33.62793897729328, -3.5252208930692497, 5.165162011403056)
```

has four distinct solutions:

```
s = 57.3895941365 , t = -16.6969433689
    A = (-33.865027354189415, 27.07409541837935, 37.59945205363035)
    C = (10.436323283003153, -8.332179814593692, 10.022267893763457)
    |A - B| = 44.5910029061
    |C - B| = 44.5910029061
    (A - B)·(C - B) = 1.70530256582e-13

s = 43.619078237 , t = 32.9673082734
    A = (-25.739183207076163, 20.5777215193455, 28.577540327140607)
    C = (-20.606016281518986, 16.45148662649085, -19.78848391300571)
    |A - B| = 34.5155582156
    |C - B| = 34.5155582156
    (A - B)·(C - B) = 1.13686837722e-13

s = -47.5886624358 , t = 83.8222109697
    A = (28.08159526800866, -22.450411211385674, -31.17825902887765)
    C = (-52.39256507303229, 41.82931682916268, -50.313918854788845)
    |A - B| = 74.0747844969
    |C - B| = 74.0747844969
    (A - B)·(C - B) = 4.54747350886e-13

s = 142.883074325 , t = 136.634726869
    A = (-84.31387768560096, 67.4064705656035, 93.61148799140805)
    C = (-85.40270813540043, 68.1840435123674, -82.01440263735996)
    |A - B| = 124.189861967
    |C - B| = 124.189861967
    (A - B)·(C - B) = -9.09494701773e-13
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it out and let you know.

Comment: For certain problems that should have a solution the algorithm doesn't give one... maybe a problem with the equation? See for example: a = (0.1836445, 0, 0.9829927);
b = (0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
c = (0, 0.3500095, 0.9367462);
B = (0.0, 0.0, 8.3);

Comment: @user479864: Checking the equation with these parameters indeed seems extremely regular but never crossing the zero (thus no real solutions). Why do you think this problem must have a solution? Can you provide one? Like it's said in the answer I've been able with random parameter sampling to create problems with 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4 distinct solutions.

Comment: I'm displaying the solutions in a 3D environment and it seems/looks very strange that there is no solution for a = (0.3266604, 0, 0.9451418), c = (0, 0.3500095, 0.9367462) but one for a = (0.3266588, -0.001026195, 0.9451418), c = (0, 0.3500095, 0.9367462), both using b and B of the above example. In this example this problem always occurs when a) the angle between AB and BC is also 90 degrees when projecting the vectors onto a plane at B where b is its normal and b) |AB| != |BC|.
I can't see a reason in my visualization why there shouldn't be a solution, but I don't have mathematical proof...

Comment: @user479864: I'm not sure I understand. Even the equation `x*x - 1e-100 = 0` has two solutions but `x*x + 1e-100 = 0` has no solutions on the real line. The full equation has degree 4 and it can have between 0 and 4 solutions in general (IOW there are parameters for all 5 cases). Of course you can find values of the parameters for which a small variation can change the number of solutions. Note there are even infinite cases with infinite solutions each (e.g. a=(1,0,0), b=(sqrt(2)/2, sqrt(2)/2, 0), c=(0,1,0), B=b).

Answer (score 0):

Write two quadratic equations for lambda, mu unknowns (just above matrix forms).
Solve this system with paper,  pen and head, or with any mathematical software like Maple, Mathematica, Matlab, Derive etc. You will have [4th order equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function). It has closed-form solution - apply Ferrari or Kardano method and get real roots, find mu, lambda, then point coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for the steps, I will give them a try and let you know.